# Pandas - problema na exclusão de uma linha

Tags: python, pandas

Olá, estou com um problema na hora de excluir uma linha em uma tabela de um arquivo .xlsx

```
caminho_arquivo_excel = r'C:\Users\A3336228\Documents\CreditLimitReviewV3\Resources\Report\teste123.xlsx'

dados = pd.read_excel(caminho_arquivo_excel, header=None)

indice_pn = dados[dados[1] == 'PN'].index[0]

dados = dados.iloc[indice_pn:]

dados = dados.drop(columns=[4, 5, 11])

dados = dados.drop(columns=[0])

dados[14] = dados[14].replace('\.', '/', regex=True).fillna('')

dados = dados.drop(1)

dados = dados.drop_duplicates()

caminho_salvar_xls = r'C:\Users\A3336228\Documents\CreditLimitReviewV3\Resources\Report\UKM_BP_DISPLAY_QZJS_RPA.xlsx'

dados.to_excel(caminho_salvar_xls, index=False, header=False)

print("Planilha salva em:", caminho_salvar_xls)
```

quando eu uso o dados = dados.drop(1) (para excluir a linha 2 do arquivo), me é retornado o erro abaixo:

[Erro axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUPvI.png)

Abaixo está a tabela sem excluir a linha 2, estou tampando os valores pois sao valores sensiveis.

[Tabela sem a linha 2 com valores sensiveis.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYpR3.png)

Alguém teria uma solução? Pois, já tentei especificar o índice e não funcionou de nada.

Abaixo está a tabela antes de entrar no drop linha 2.

[antes de entrar no drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBOWk.png)

Answer (score -1):

Um de seus drops, não está bem especificado o que é para dropar, o dados = dados.drop(1), experimenta especificar melhor, usado axis e label. Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path_file = (os.path.realpath(os.curdir) + '\\Files\\Book.xlsx')

df = pd.read_excel(path_file)

print(df)

df = (df.drop(axis=0,labels=1))

print(df)
```